# How to properly create this barplot in R using ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, figure

example data are as follows:

```
library(tidyverse)
df=tibble(type=c('grass','forest','desert','crop'),
          temperature=c(0.6206,0.6132,0.6235,0.6134),
          precipitation=c(252,290,198,337),
          radiation=c(156,177,123,205))
dff <- df %>% pivot_longer(cols = -type,
                           names_to = 'n',
                           values_to = 'v')
dff
ggplot(data = dff)+
  geom_bar(aes(x=type,y=v,
               fill=n),
           stat = 'identity',
           position = 'dodge')
```

[image]

The problem is that 'temperature' variable is too low to obsereve it!!!
How can I make a better figure?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: IMHO a dodged barchart does not make that much sense as you are plotting three different variables with different units of measurement. Instead I would suggest to facet by `n`, i.e. `+ facet_wrap(~n, scales="free_y")`

Comment: Knowing no other context to the situation, I would agree with @stefan. These have three different scales, so use facets to have three different scales. The only other alternative I can think of is if you are trying to understand relative values, you could use the base function `scale` on the values, but that gives you a very different visual

Comment: This is not really a programming question; it's a data visualization question. If you don't know what you want the output to be, you should first get some visualization advice from a site like [stats.se].

Comment: I agree that it is a data visualization question.Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would agree with the comments here. You have three different variables of different dimensions and these should not really be plotted on the same scale at all. Although you *could* add a second axis, it might be easier, more visually appealing, and more understandable if you represent the three different dimensions of temperature, precipitation and radiation on a single plot using the x, y and color aesthetics:

```r
ggplot(df, aes(temperature, precipitation, fill = radiation)) +
  geom_point(shape = 21, size = 10, color = 'white', alpha = 0.5) +
  geom_point(shape = 21, size = 5, color = 'white') +
  geom_text(aes(label = type), position = position_nudge(0.001, 10)) +
  scale_fill_viridis_c(option = 'C') + 
  theme_minimal(base_size = 20) +
  xlim(0.61, 0.63) +
  coord_cartesian(clip = 'off') +
  theme(panel.border = element_rect(fill = NA, color = 'gray80',
                                    linewidth = 0.5),
        panel.grid = element_line(linewidth = 0.4),
        panel.grid.minor.x = element_blank())
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is a suggestion using two y axis. Also not the ideal solution:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  mutate(space = NA) %>% 
  mutate(temperature = temperature*100) %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = -type,
                           names_to = 'n',
                           values_to = 'v') %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=type,y=v,fill=n))+
  geom_col(position = position_dodge())+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("blue", "red", "NA", "purple"),
                    limits = c("precipitation","radiation","","temperature")) +
  scale_y_continuous(
    name = "Precipitation & Radiation",
    sec.axis = sec_axis(~.*0.01, name = "Temp")
  )+
  xlab("\nType")+
  theme_bw(14)+
  theme(
    axis.title.y = element_text(color = "grey", size=13, face="bold"),
    axis.title.y.right = element_text(color = "purple", size=13, face="bold"),
    axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1)
  )
```

[image]