# How to remove a single item from legend in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, legend

This question is related to this [How to properly create this barplot in R using ggplot2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75697100/how-to-properly-create-this-barplot-in-r-using-ggplot2)

If have this code which produces this plot:

```
library(tidyverse)
df=tibble(type=c('grass','forest','desert','crop'),
          temperature=c(0.6206,0.6132,0.6235,0.6134),
          precipitation=c(252,290,198,337),
          radiation=c(156,177,123,205))


df %>% 
  mutate(space = NA) %>% 
  mutate(temperature = temperature*100) %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = -type,
                           names_to = 'n',
                           values_to = 'v') %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=type,y=v,fill=n))+
  geom_col(position = position_dodge())+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("blue", "red", "white", "purple"))+
  scale_y_continuous(
    name = "Precipitation & Radiation",
    sec.axis = sec_axis(~.*0.01, name = "Temp")
  )+
  xlab("\nType")+
  theme_bw(14)+
  theme(
    axis.title.y = element_text(color = "grey", size=13, face="bold"),
    axis.title.y.right = element_text(color = "purple", size=13, face="bold"),
    axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1)
  )
```

[image]

**I want to remove the "space" item and keep the gap between radiation and temperature.**

I have tried coloring them white, but failed.

**Desired output:**
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your `scale_fill_manual` to:

```
...
 scale_fill_manual(values = c("blue", "red", "NA", "purple"),
limits = c("precipitation","radiation","","temperature")) +
...
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Look at the desired output: We need the gap between radiation and temperature and space must disappear!

Answer (score 1):

Set the text color to white for `space`, and use the `ggtext` package to give each legend element its own text color.

```
library(ggtext)
  df %>% 
    mutate(space = NA) %>% 
    mutate(temperature = temperature*100) %>% 
    pivot_longer(cols = -type, names_to = 'n', values_to = 'v') %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x=type,y=v,fill=n))+
    geom_col(position = position_dodge())+
    # Here is the change
    scale_fill_manual(
      values = c("blue", "red", "white", "purple"), 
      labels = c("<span style='color:black'>precipitation</span>", "<span style='color:black'>radiation</span>", "<span style='color:white'>space</span>", "<span style='color:black'>temperature</span>"))+
    scale_y_continuous(
      name = "Precipitation & Radiation",
      sec.axis = sec_axis(~.*0.01, name = "Temp")
    )+
    xlab("\nType")+
    theme_bw(14)+
    theme(
      axis.title.y = element_text(color = "grey", size=13, face="bold"),
      axis.title.y.right = element_text(color = "purple", size=13, face="bold"),
      axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1),
      ## Add this line too
      legend.text=element_markdown()
    )
```

Note that if you want something to appear as transparent, you can use the hexcode `#FFFFFF00`. You may want to use this instead of `'white'`.

Comment: Thank you. Look at the desired output: We need the gap between radiation and temperature!

Comment: @TarJae -- this answer works now. It's a bit hackish - we just set the legend text color to white so you can't see it.

Comment: could you clean your code please. I seems to have issues. thanks

Comment: @TarJae sorry about that -- it should run now

Answer (score 1):

And yet another option would be to simply replace `"space"` by an empty string `""` via an `if_else` and the `labels` argument:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  mutate(space = NA) %>%
  mutate(temperature = temperature * 100) %>%
  pivot_longer(
    cols = -type,
    names_to = "n",
    values_to = "v"
  ) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = type, y = v, fill = n)) +
  geom_col(position = position_dodge()) +
  scale_fill_manual(
    values = c("blue", "red", "white", "purple"),
    labels = ~ if_else(.x == "space", "", .x)
  ) +
  scale_y_continuous(
    name = "Precipitation & Radiation",
    sec.axis = sec_axis(~ . * 0.01, name = "Temp")
  ) +
  xlab("\nType") +
  theme_bw(14) +
  theme(
    axis.title.y = element_text(color = "grey", size = 13, face = "bold"),
    axis.title.y.right = element_text(color = "purple", size = 13, face = "bold"),
    axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 0.5, hjust = 1)
  )
```

[image]

Comment: Very clever. I decided to accept the solution by @SALAR.

Answer (score -1):

Taken the empty string from @mfg3z0 instead of "space" and setting `drop = FALSE` keeps the space:

```r
library(tidyverse)
df=tibble(type=c('grass','forest','desert','crop'),
          temperature=c(0.6206,0.6132,0.6235,0.6134),
          precipitation=c(252,290,198,337),
          radiation=c(156,177,123,205))


df %>% 
  mutate(space = NA) %>% 
  mutate(temperature = temperature*100) %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = -type,
               names_to = 'n',
               values_to = 'v') %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=type,y=v,fill=n))+
  geom_col(position = position_dodge())+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("precipitation" = "blue", "radiation" = "red", "white", "temperature" = "purple"),
                    drop = FALSE)+
  scale_y_continuous(
    name = "Precipitation & Radiation",
    sec.axis = sec_axis(~.*0.01, name = "Temp")
  )+
  xlab("\nType")+
  theme_bw(14)+
  theme(
    axis.title.y = element_text(color = "grey", size=13, face="bold"),
    axis.title.y.right = element_text(color = "purple", size=13, face="bold"),
    axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1)
  )
#> Warning: Removed 4 rows containing missing values (geom_col).
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-03-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Sorry. But the gap is not there when I run the code!?

Comment: which ggplot2 version do you use? I've used a bit older one, probably the behaviour changed. I think with the current version, @SALAR's solution with giving the order as the `limit` argument is the best solution

Comment: > packageVersion("ggplot2")
[1] ‘3.4.1’